how to smooth a road while holding max and min z points constant?
I am building a road for a racing simulator - however the land itself is too bumpy! What smoothing operation should i use to keep the overall altitude change constant but get rid of those pesky bumps?
I think it is laplace smooth modifier but just seeking experienced advice.


Use Sculpt Mode and a Smooth brush.
In the right-hand Tool menu, under Symmetry, set Lock to X and Y so you only smooth along the Z axis, preventing your track from losing width.
Set the brush to a wide radius and then brush over the bumpy areas of your track mesh.


this technique ended up working the best. Thanks!

Using a smooth modifier with only the Z-Axis enabled and alot of iterations seems to work pretty well for me.

